# SVN branch rename confict

Tags: xcode, svn

I renamed svn branch let say from `BR1` to `BRANCH_1`.
Then I found that there is some uncommitted code in `BR1` in my other system If I take update then it may give tree conflict. how to resolve this and commit my uncommitted code to new `BRANCH_1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

1. Export whole directory with uncommited files

`svn export /path/to/BR1 /tmp/BR1`

Export command will extract your files without SVN informations

2. Checkout BRANCH_1 let's say to /path/to/BRANCH_1
3. Copy /tmp/BR1 to /path/to/BRANCH_1 and erase all files
4. Commit files from /path/to/BRANCH_1